# How to create an Employee with an Action

Tags: acumatica

I'm trying to create an Employee with an action.

I have identified the minimum required fields in the UI as:
- EmployeeID (key field)
- LastName (Contact DAC)
- Employee class
- Department

I initially tried to enter those values only expecting that SetValueExt would run the default events and assign other requested fields, but after running the action I got different messages requesting those additional fields. So I included them as well.

My code is looking as follows:

```
        public PXAction<EPEmployee> testAction;
    [PXButton]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "EXTENDED")]
    protected virtual IEnumerable TestAction(PXAdapter adapter)
    {
        EmployeeMaint employeeMaintGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<EmployeeMaint>();
        employeeMaintGraph.Clear();


        EPEmployee epEmployeeRow = new EPEmployee();
        epEmployeeRow.AcctCD = "CODED";
        epEmployeeRow.AcctName = "employee";
        epEmployeeRow.Status = "A";
        employeeMaintGraph.Employee.Insert(epEmployeeRow);

        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.vendorClassID>(epEmployeeRow, "EMPDEFAULT");
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.classID>(epEmployeeRow, "EMPDEFAULT");
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.departmentID>(epEmployeeRow, "ADMIN");
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.positionLineCntr>(epEmployeeRow, 1);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.consolidateToParent>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.allowOverrideCury>(epEmployeeRow, true);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.allowOverrideRate>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.payToParent>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.acctName>(epEmployeeRow, "employee");
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.vendor1099>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.taxAgency>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.updClosedTaxPeriods>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.taxReportRounding>(epEmployeeRow, "R");
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.taxUseVendorCurPrecision>(epEmployeeRow, true);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.taxReportFinPeriod>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.taxPeriodType>(epEmployeeRow, "M");
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.enableTaxStartDate>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.landedCostVendor>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.isLaborUnion>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.lineDiscountTarget>(epEmployeeRow, "E");
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.ignoreConfiguredDiscounts>(epEmployeeRow, false);
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.sVATReversalMethod>(epEmployeeRow, "D");
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.sVATInputTaxEntryRefNbr>(epEmployeeRow, "M");
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.sVATOutputTaxEntryRefNbr>(epEmployeeRow, "M");
        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Cache.SetValueExt<EPEmployee.type>(epEmployeeRow, "EP");

        employeeMaintGraph.CurrentEmployee.Update(epEmployeeRow);

        Contact contactRow = new Contact();
        contactRow.LastName = "lastname";
        employeeMaintGraph.Contact.Insert(contactRow);


        Address addressRow = new Address();
        addressRow.CountryID = "US";
        employeeMaintGraph.Address.Insert(addressRow);


        employeeMaintGraph.Actions.PressSave();

        return adapter.Get();}
```

With this current version I get the message:
 "**Error: 'Branch' cannot be empty. Error: 'Default Location' cannot be empty. Error: 'Route Emails' cannot be empty.**"

I have looked for the Branch field in the database in BAccount, Employee, Vendor (employee DAC inherits from it), contact and Address tables with no luck.
Any idea what the error may be?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the code snippet below for an example to create an Employee within an action:

```
public PXAction<EPEmployee> CreateEmployee;
[PXButton]
[PXUIField(DisplayName = "Create Employee")]
protected void createEmployee()
{
    EmployeeMaint employeeMaintGraph = PXGraph.CreateInstance<EmployeeMaint>();
    EPEmployee epEmployeeRow = new EPEmployee();
    epEmployeeRow.AcctCD = "EMPLOYEE1";
    epEmployeeRow = employeeMaintGraph.Employee.Insert(epEmployeeRow);

    Contact contactRow = employeeMaintGraph.Contact.Current = employeeMaintGraph.Contact.Select();
    contactRow.FirstName = "John";
    contactRow.LastName = "Green";
    employeeMaintGraph.Contact.Update(contactRow);

    Address addressRow = employeeMaintGraph.Address.Current = employeeMaintGraph.Address.Select();
    addressRow.CountryID = "US";
    addressRow = employeeMaintGraph.Address.Update(addressRow);
    addressRow.State = "DC";
    employeeMaintGraph.Address.Update(addressRow);

    epEmployeeRow.VendorClassID = "EMPSTAND";
    epEmployeeRow.DepartmentID = "FINANCE";
    employeeMaintGraph.Employee.Update(epEmployeeRow);

    employeeMaintGraph.Actions.PressSave();

    throw new PXRedirectRequiredException(employeeMaintGraph, null);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ruslan. I will give it a shot

Comment: Thank you @RuslanDev. Worked great. I saw my errors. 
1 follow up question: Do you assign **employeeMaintGraph.Contact.Current = employeeMaintGraph.Contact.Select();** for a specific reason?
After debugging, it seems that the content for that Data View is already available after the initial Insert.
I tried it like this **Contact contactRow = employeeMaintGraph.Contact.Current**, and seems to save the record correctly

Comment: When inserting a new Employee, `employeeMaintGraph.Contact.Current` will always return the main contact record as the contact record gets automatically inserted into cache and therefore becomes available via the Current property of PXCache/Data View. The use of `Select()` method is a little more generic since it will work in all possible scenarios, whether you need to insert new Employee or update an existing one.

Comment: Thanks @RuslanDev